# zend db quote (escape) on insert array adds quotes to string

Tags: php, mysql, string, zend-framework, zend-db

I am inserting an array into my dbatabase using Zend and I am trying to use the $zenddb->quote($string) function to escape my values, but it is adding quotes into the strings, so the quotes are still there in the database after I insert it. Am I using it incorrectly?

```
$data['tournament_id'] = $this->zdb->quote($_POST['winners_tournament_id']);
$data['user_id']       = $this->zdb->quote($_SESSION['user']);
$data['user_name'] = $this->zdb->quote($_SESSION['first_name']);

$insert = $this->zdb->insert("submitters", $data);

//print_r($data) looks like this:
Array
(
    [tournament_id] => '55'
    [user_id] => '2182609'
    [user_name] => 'eric'
)
```

The strings are being inserted with quotes around them, and the numbers are being inserted as 0 (zero). When I remove $zenddb->quote(), it works fine. But then how do I escape them properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use the quote function in this case.  Because you're using the  Zend_Db_Table adapter ($db->insert and $db->update) the data from your array is already escaped.  Most likely this is adding an extra set of quotes before inserting or updating the data.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So, if I understand, I don't need to quote it manually if I am inserting it as an array, because zend already quotes each value in the array when I insert it this way?